# metaquestion on TeX in 20 years

Tags: tex-core

I will probably be dead in 20 years (old age related), but I am wondering where TeX (my most used program) is ultimately going.  I think most of the core development team is even older than I am.  TeX's design is not easy to understand and has not been enticing to a new generation of programmers.

(The learning curve and monolithic design is probably why no one has written a version that dispatches document parts separated by `\clearpage` macros [incl chapters] to different processor cores.  This really shouldn't be too difficult...except it's TeX.  Correction: Because macros can appear everywhere and not just in the preamble, this was a false statement.  Only documents with all macros in the preamble could be dispatched.)

Is there hope that the baton will be picked up by a newer generation and TeX will be rejuvenated?  Or are we getting close to the end?

Comment: You have good foreseeing eyes.... ha ha ha ... :-D

Comment: You could try asking some of the core latex team what they were doing when latex2e was released, Marcel and Phelype for example.....

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I was still at school ...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I've got an older sister who is about as old as 2e...

Comment: Sidenote: Macro expansion is the way to go. TeX has it, SAS has it. The processing stream, the "circuit", if I can call it that, can be linear, or plug into itself, or unfold into a cascade or a net (and that way lies AI). A bit like a lua table can have a field which is another table. This "embed-ability" I'm trying to describe maps onto the number system, and so is equally fractal. Plain computer languages are not "meta" enough (yet), although if you start with pointers rather than typed functions and variables, that's a good start. (So, does that make `\verb` a sort of "prime"? :) )

Comment: macro expansion may be the way to go, but there are probably 100,000 good Python programmers for every good macro programmer...I guess I should have asked how many tex and latex core developers are under 40 years old.

Answer (score 4):

A few of the things out there:

## luaTeX

I'm not too enamored with this if only because there are lots of little incompatibilities (e.g., line breaking after dashes is not enabled by default) and its font handling is not easily compatible with XeTeX or pdfTeX. Some TeX macro packages have begun requiring luaTeX as the engine (IIRC ConTeXt is one such, but I could be wrong). Lua has the advantage of being a less arcane programming language than TeX macro expansion.

## sile

I've not looked too closely at this, but it's kind of working from the outside in on layout and has only recently begun supporting mathematics. Its connection with TeX is a bit tenuous and TeX-style math input is apparently not the preferred input.

## finl

This one is mine. At last estimate I have [29 years](https://www.dahosek.com/the-big-countdown-9/). I'm hoping to have enough of [finl](https://finl.xyz) done before that for it to have a life of its own without me. At the moment, I'm working on a parser for a LaTeX-like markup language (most styling will be simple declarative things specified in yaml files, but there will be programmability through an embedded interpreter, the language of which will be a normal programming language). User commands will be possible, but will be deliberately non–Turing complete (the whole macro expansion thing is a bit of a nightmare—There's a part of me that's tempted to say that user commands (and commands like `\input` should have a different sigil to make it clear that they'll behave differently from “proper” finl commands in that they'll get executed immediately.

The structure of the program is more akin to a contemporary compiler architecture in that the first step is to take an input file and compile it to an intermediate representation, so schematically, something like:

```
\section{This is a section\footnote{It 
    has a footnote with \verb+\verbatim+ text}}
and it's followed by text
```

will first reduce to something like:

- **section**

  1. Token argument containing

     - `This is a section`
     - **footnote**

       1. Token argument containing

          - `It has a footnote containing`
          - **verb**

            1. Unparsed argument containing

               - `\verbatim`
          - `text`
- `and it's followed by text`

The basic markup language is designed to be familiar to LaTeX users with some pain points removed (note, for example, the fact that there's no problem with putting `\verb` in the argument to another command).

This can then be rendered to a desired output format (e.g., PDF, HTML, ePub, onscreen display, Word, inDesign, etc.)

Likewise, the front-end parser can be easily replaced with something else, that can still parse down to the intermediate format, so an equivalent input could be say, markdown:

```
 # This is a section[^1]
 [^1]: It has a footnote with `\verbatim` text
 and it's followed by text
```

or perhaps an XML-based input:

```
<h1>This is a section<footnote>It has 
    a footnote 
    with<verbatim><![CDATA[\verbatim]]></verbatim> 
    text</h1>
<p>and it's followed by text</p>
```

(this style of handling things similar to how modern compilers like gcc or llvm manage to support multiple languages and multiple targets).

Comment: ConTeXt used to require luatex but moved on to luametatex.

Comment: Btw: I love your finl ideas. Is there an up to date repo to follow? https://github.com/dahosek/finl seems a bit inactive.

Comment: Right now the only code that's out is the charsub module which is at https://github.com/dahosek/finl_charsub The parse code is far from finished and while you can easily find my last checkin, it's not worth looking at beyond the readme and that info is presented better at https://www.finl.xyz/2021/11/06/revised-definition-of-commands-environments/ (comments are welcome).

Comment: I wish you a lot of luck, too.  please keep macros in the preamble, so that \clearpage separated parts can be passed to different processor cores at some point in the future.

Comment: Yep, `\DefineUserCommand` will be a preamble-only command. Because it's a multi-stage process, there are clear steps that can be used in parallelization with Unix pipe-style communication between stages.

Comment: Part of why LaTeX has to allow new commands anywhere is because there aren't really variables per se (and the various registers were later additions to the original TeX implementation as DEK and other early users found themselves reusing the limited predefined register-like structures for other purposes.